What could power a Medieval Tank?
I had to refine both the title and the question. So for my refinement, I'm working with mostly 16th century technology from Europe and a few bits of technology from before the 16th century, but the main crux of my issue is this, what would be the most practical thing I could used to power a "Medieval Tank"?
For clarification sake, It's made from a Hussite War Wagon, it has a field cannon strapped to it, armor plating, & swivel guns attached.
I've done some research on What's been called an aeolipile steam engine https://youtu.be/xo_bNl447o4?si=SxOUHrTCsQVQUADV
I've seen Da Vinci's "Tank" Design https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo%27s_fighting_vehicle but that was if I remember correctly man powered.
And then there's horse power as well.

There is no such thing as a "rudimentary" seam turbine. (And the aeolipile was not "little more" than a toy; it was nothing more than a toy.) Moreover, without modern mechanical and metalurgical technology there was no way to couple the steam turbine to the wheels. There is a vast technological chasm between the early 15th century of the Hussite Wars and the late 19th century of the first turbine powered steam ship, the Turbinia of 1894. Ask yourself why Stephenson didn't use steam turbines in his locomotives...

I'm actually talking about more the rotating spit device from 1551, that was called a steam turbine or at least acted like one according to accounts. I'm under the assumption that if that combined with a more advanced Aeoplipile could be used for power this thing, and if so what pros and cons would that have?

There were no steam-powered roasting spits in the Ottoman Empire, in the 16th century or at any time. I should know, as the medieval principalitties which eventually united to form my country were Ottoman protectorates (or vassals, if you prefer) for a long time. A drawing on paper is not a steam turbine.

(My point is that steam turbines are very much more difficult to make and use than piston steam engines. I can maybe sort of imagine an eccentric medieval king spend a fortune to make one very bad very inefficient piston steam engine. A practicable steam turbine, no way.)

@OP: Please clearify: Is the feasibility of that steam engine and the tank in question or is it given fact in your scenario? We can either argue about metal works in medieval ages given the blueprint was known - or we can scrutinize this steam powered vehicle given it exists (in medieval times). I think you are asking the latter, since you want to know pros&cons. Please edit your question text accordingly.

@Antares: Unfortunately, if they do have practicable steam turbines this means that they also have modern-ish steel manufacturing and machining capabilities, complete with precise measurements, lathes, gearboxes and so on. That civilization is definitely not medieval.

I mean you can use it for something practical https://youtu.be/R4OWIcSeWFk?si=DEYAcm6wlJnqdrPp if these two guys can do it why can't an entire team devoted to finding new ways of using existing technology?

@Altarious - there is a world of difference between coming up with s new idea and reverse engineering a bunch of known technologies. especially with access to modern tooling.

@Altarious the steam jack AKA steam powered spit rotating device is from the 1800's the based on the rotating spit device powed by a dog on treadmill, that is from the 1500's. Thats probably where you got confused. the issue with a tank is it needs tremoundous torque, meaning it needs a very advanced egine and materials.

@Altarious: That video shows, in chronological order: modern pressure vessels; modern machined bearings; modern screws; modern metal tubing; a very modern pressure gauge; a modern gas burner; a modern worm gear (reducing the rotation speed by 44×); and so on. And at the end of all this modernity, the efficiency of the contraption is between 1% and 2%, worse than Watt's 1776 piston steam engine.

A fantasy setting can build anything you want with sufficient appeals to the mystical properties of werewolf tears, dragon fossils, doomed pacts with devious fairies, and the occasional demonic sacrifice. If those aren't to your liking, I would suggest removing 'fantasy' from the question.

What would the point be of a steam-powered tank on a medieval battlefield? Even a WWI-era tank would be a tremendous waste of materials in the absence of the tactics they were meant to counter (machine guns, massive trench works manned by rifle troops). Without those threats they don't seem to have anything to recommend them over horse-drawn war wagons or even pavisiers in terms of slow, but well-protected missile troops.

@John yes that's exactly where I got confused. I was basically under the impression that while it was around in the 1500's it could feasibly be used. Although I do admit my "tanks" are wooden so I didn't think they'd need to be as powerful as modern ones.

@Cadence well I have them because I do have guns, trenches and other stuff of war around that can make them relevant.

See also If the Romans found one working steam engine would they have been able to copy and use it? And while we're at it, your title is asking a very different question compared to the question found in the body of your text. Please remember that asking more than one quesiton is a specific reason for closing posts.

@JBH that is true. I have to admit to being half asleep when asking this first thing in the morning, and my hazy brain figured this made sense. I'll see about refining it so it makes more sense really quick.

@OP: Is a ship okay or has it to be a land vehicle?

Turbine, no. Other ways, perhaps.
In his studies, Leonardo da Vinci had noted that the difficulty in moving horizontally something was due to the ups-and-downs of the path, and had even surmised that friction was caused by the presence of microscopic ups-and-downs, and that if it were possible to "smooth" the actual travel of a cart, regardless of what the wheels were doing, a heavy cart could have been moved by a small child.
He also dreamed of what a covered, armored cart could have done to an enemy army, and wrote in 1482 in a letter "Covered, armored carts that... could penetrate among the enemies who, as many as they might be, would be unable to attack them".
Finally, he had also studied and even improved old designs that had donkeys and oxen moving in circles to supply motive power.
With a bit of hand-waving (weights don't really work out), you might be able to have a large covered cart moved by simple mechanisms.
The first sort-of "Tank" was designed around 1480.

The real problem here might be that this kind of contraptions would be extremely vulnerable to Greek fire or the 15-th century equivalent of a Molotov cocktail.

Now that's just unfair. Da Vinci diagrams a badly designed, never-built wagon that wouldn't have been able to move and would have been tactically useless if it did, and that means we're supposed to forget whatever forgotten Mesopotamian warlord came up with the first covered battering ram in 2500 BC - and actually used it to crush his enemies, see them driven before him, and hear the lamentations of the women?

@gs I did say that weights wouldn't work out :-) -- but the use case for a covered battering ram is different from that of a tank.

No way.
Heron's steam "turbine" was a toy with incredibly low efficiency. A steam turbine is technologically much more challenging than a reciprocating steam engine, and even those are not feasible at a "medieval" level of technology. If you "uplift" your technology to a point where they can make steam engines, either you have an anomalous high-tech enclave with supply problems, or you have "no longer medieval" technology.
The first applications of steam engines were stationary. They came at a time which was "within shouting distance" of the very late medieval period, but it took another century or two to get pressures high enough to make mobile use practical. Higher pressure means better metal (to prevent boiler explosions) and better manufacturing tolerances (to prevent leaks).

Better steam engines also required better designs to go with the higher pressures.  Newcomen's engine had such a voracious appetite for coal that it could only be used to pump water out of coal mines.

not to mention, that if you had technology to make a steam engine good enough to power a tank, you are far, far more advanced in just about every type of technology than what was possible in the 16th century. All that metallurgy, practical physics and engineering knowledge would bleed into every other aspect of life, catapulting the world into late18th/early 19th century level.

Siege Towers were basically medieval tanks.  They were powered by simply being pushed along the ground by as many men as could be convinced to do so or pulled by oxen (in the case of a siege,  by using a pulley system and looped ropes, so the oxen were pulling away from the castle.)
The fact that some of the men are outside the tank and therefore vulnerable to fire is not necessarily a stumbling block,  even today the Russian doctrine is for troops to ride on top of armoured vehicles.

Essentially what you want is a force causing rotation to a shaft. There are multiple ways to achieve this:
Option 1) Wind-mill.
Option 2) 'Battery' via storing energy in "rubber-band"-style contraption. 
Option 2b) Gravity batteries. Lift heavy items and potential energy does the work for you. 
Option 3) Human/animal running in a hamster wheel. 
Option 4) Run it downhill and use the breaking force to power it. 
Option 4b) push it with humans/animals and use option 4. 
Option 4c) Use sails instead of pushing. 
Option 5 collect rainwater and use it in a water-wheel. (Same idea as windmill)
Then there is always magic. ;)

2 horses and a transmition system
Human and even animal power have a hard time moving something as heavy as an armored vehicle. If we assume that your tank needs to be able to travel over rough terrain, a single horse will only be able to pull anywhere from 500-1500kg depending on how rough the terrain is.  That said, 2 horses working together can pull 3 times this amount (because friction is weird like that). For purposes of this question, I'm going to be taking the horses off of the ground and putting them on a treadmill inside of the tank. This means that you have 2500-4500kg of pull with 1000kg of horse.  The reason we want a treadmill is because of a little thing called mechanical advantage.  By using a system of gears, you can use the power of a horse running and translate it into a lower speed and higher torque for overcoming difficult terrain while still maintaining a reasonable speed.
Now let's figure how heavy your tank is. If we want it to have a 6 man crew, then we can assume ~600kg of men and kit. A standard field cannon with 20-30 shots would weight ~200-600kg, then the body of the tank is going to depend a lot on what you mean by armored.  If we assume you need to be armored against common medieval weapons from all sides and light field artillery from the front, then we can assume you need ~3-5tons of armor (you don't need nearly as much as modern tanks because you aren't facing modern firearms) and an additional 2 tons of for the wagon and its mechanical bits.  This gives us a total weight of about 6.8-9.2 tons. For sake of argument, I'll just round up to an even 10 tons just in case I'm forgetting something.
Now let's figure out some scenarios:
Horses can maintain a low canter for a pretty long time; so, horses can maintain a 15kph speed for hours.  If you assume a good road, then a 2:1 gear ratio will allow your horses to move your 10 ton tank a bit faster than most people can walk.  over slightly rough terrain, you can pop the ratio up to about 3:1 and you will be moving at a human walking speed almost exactly.  Over rough terrain like sand, you can kick it all the way up to 4:1, and pick it up to a brisk canter and still keep pace with your infantry.  When it comes time to full charge the enemy on a battlefield, you can choose 3:1 or 4:1 depending on the terrain and bring your horses up to a full run and your tank will move a little bit faster than most people can charge.

I would replace horses with donkeys, mules, or even camels. Short of some mutant Clydesdale, horses are not built for this kind of disastrously hard work, and are kinda expensive.
Oxen are less efficient than horses, but being very docile, significantly more likely to tolerate being locked inside a tank. A Horse trapped in a dark, stuffy, box with a bunch of humans, no way to escape and forced to do back-breaking work? This is a recipe for a 500kg animal going batshit and pulverizing the crew in its mad rampage before it dies of cardiac failure.

@GoingDurden Draft horses are specifically bred for this kind of work, and have much more docile temperaments than war horses.  The reason to went with a draft horse over an ox was shoulder width.  A horse does not have the pull strength of an ox, but it has more power for its body width and can sustain higher speeds allowing you to use mechanical advantage as a force multiplier.  This means you can get away with a narrower tank, which  means a narrower front armor plate, which means a lot less armor weight.  Though a mule would also work.

Im skeptical one can easily breed a horse docile enough to work as a tank's engine, this is an environment as stressful to a horse as you can possibly design. And if it could be done, which I strongly doubt, the horse would easily overheat or over-tire and die.

@GoingDurden Horses are highly trainable and breedable animals.  Cataphracts trained their horses to wear hot, heavy, armor and charge with blinders on at screaming and violent enemies.  Part of the horses training should involve banging on the walls of the tank and screaming while on the outside.  Training a horse to deal with scary noise is not hard, and blinding them actually helps.  As for the heat, the tanks could have hatches that can be opened to let in plenty of fresh air while on the move and only closed up when going into battle.
